# What is the best way to add more than one bvh file actions in a makehuman model?

Tags: animation, makehuman

I learnt how to use MakeHuman model and importing it in blender, and use the "Load and retarget" button of the makehumans addon.

It works very well, but I want to use more actions to the makehuman model so that for example, from frame 0 to 100, the personnage is walking, and from frame 101 to 150, the perso is running, and from frame 151 till the end of frame the perso is fighting;

What is the best and efficient way to accomplish this? All my BVH files comes from [cgspeed](https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion)

Comment: Feel can't answer as not using makehuman to test.  I'd assume the retarget makes an action.  If you are familiar with the NLA, you can drop that action to a track strip (where you define start n end frames) and then retarget another etc.

Comment: I tried to manipulate this NLA, with no success; I surely did something wrong; What i've tried is, create a new empty scene, import bvh file then save it as a blend file; When it's done, I came back to my makehuman retargeted scene, where I clicked on File->Append => "the_bvhfile.blend", open its action folder, then as needed, I saw a new action added in my makehuman scene in the NLA; BUT the second action are not playing when I tap ALT+A :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know how to load and retarget a bvh animation, i will try to explain how to use the nla editor to play some actions in a sequence

First you might want to open a dopesheet editor and set its mode to `Action Editor`. Every time you load a BVH animation the current action gets replaced by a new action. However every action uses the fake user (the background of the  F-Button is darkened) and thus remains in the blend file even when its saved and reloaded.

[image: action editor]

By clicking [image: action icon] in the second highlighted box you can choose the current action for your animation. When you are done and loaded all animations you want to enqueue, press the [image: x] button to the right to unlink the action from the armature. It should look like this.

[image: action unlinked]

Now open the NLA editor. You can also choose and unlink the action in the Properties Panel (Press <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle it)

[image: nla editor]

Choose `Add -> Add Tracks` from the Menu below. Move the cursor(green line) to frame `0` (click and drag) and choose `Add -> Add Action Strip` where you choose your action you want to play first from the dropdown menu. Move the cursor beyond the yellow bar representing the action strip and add your next strip.

It should look like this afterwards
[image: result]

You can add additional tracks and stack them. The options for blending the strips can be found in the Properties Panel

[image: blending strips]

You might want to create your own actions and only keyframe specific parts like the root bone and put it on top of the stack to override and control the motion.

For further informations see [NLA Editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/nla.html). Here is [a link to a video](https://youtu.be/wVN1b7ScfqA) showing the steps described above.

Comment: Really nice, i'm going to try this at lunch time, and i'll come back here :)

Comment: I followed like this: I imported MHX file, I click on "Load and Retarget" from the makehuman addon every time i need to add a new bvh file; Then I removed the keyframes from the DOPE SHEET as you suggested, but I have a trouble in the NLA, the first action strip that I loaded looks like this => [link](http://adiaf.16mb.com/img/error.png), even when I use other bvh files, it keeps having this behaviour, any idea?

Comment: Oh finally i found it, i just have not to delete the frames using X in the dop sheet panel :p, Thank you sear